# Complex linq query to validate sum of child units using the same datatable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following datatable, which has Units information.   The Units have a surface in square meters.
However the units can be split into subunits, in the datatable there is a ParentUnitID to know if that unit is splitted or not.

I need to validate that the sum of the surface of the child units, is equal to the surface of the parent unit.

[image]

The current code is something like:

```
private void ValidateUnitsStep(WorkspaceCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Get data from step
    GetUnitsData();
    UserControlUnits Units = GetSmartPartByType<UserControlUnits>();

    if (_unitDataSet.Unit.HasErrors)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    DataRow[] rows = _unitDataSet.Unit.Select("ParentUnitId !=" + string.Empty);
            foreach(DataRow dr in rows)
    {

    }
}
```

I would like to do this with LINQ.   [image: Linq Complex Query]

Edit:
Yes, thats also possible, up to 2 levels of childs only

Unit A (100 sqm)

-UnitA1 (70)

```
  -UnitA11 (20)

  -UnitA12 (20)

  -UnitA12 (30)
```

-UnitA2 (30)

```
  -UnitA21 (20)

  -UnitA22 (10)
```

Comment: Can child units be parents in turn?

Comment: Yes, thats also possible, up to 2 levels of childs only  

Unit A (100 sqm)
  -UnitA1 (70)
      -UnitA11 (20)
      -UnitA12 (20)
      -UnitA12 (30)
  -UnitA2 (30)
      -UnitA21 (20)
      -UnitA22 (10)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to organize it, but the comments does not allow formating, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation using [linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)

(1 level of children, but I'm sure you can work out for 2 levels)

```
// Group the records by parent ID (potentially null)
var childrenByParentID = _unitDataSet.Unit.AsEnumerable().
                         ToLookup(child => child.Field<int?>("ParentUnitId"));

// Parents = children with no parent
var parentsByID = childrenByParentID[null].ToLookup(parent => parent.Field<int>("UnitID"));

// Look for the first group which sum of surfaces is not the same as the parent's surface
var invalidGroup = childrenByParentID.FirstOrDefault(group => 
{
  bool invalid = false;  

  if (group.Key != null)
  {
    // Not the parents group
    var currentParent = parentsByID[group.Key]);

    var totalSurface = group.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Surface"));
    invalid = (totalSurface != currentParent.Field<int>("Surface"));
  }

  return invalid;
});

if (invalidGroup != null)
{
  // .. do something special
}
```

Comment: I have some compiler errors I addded a screenshot to the question. System.Data.Linq is already present.

Comment: @Luis, source code updated again and performance improved if you have many units...